# How to add a field/parameter on primary key?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I work with Symfony2.0 and Doctrine, and I created this entity:

```
class MetaInformationsQuestionUser
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Myproject\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User")
   */
  private $user;

  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Myproject\Bundle\QuestionsBundle\Entity\MetaInformationsQuestion")
   */
  private $metainformationsquestion;

  /**
   * @var datetime $created
   *
   * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
   * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
   */
  private $created;

  /**
   * @var datetime $updated
   *
   * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
   * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
   */
  private $updated;

  /**
   * @var array $score
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="score", type="array", nullable="true")
   */
  private $score;
```

So this entity is a link for a many-to-many relation with attributes. (in this case, the score and creation and update dates).

My idea is to add a record of every question that each user plays, with the score he gets.

My problem is that I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-3' for key 'PRIMARY'

So my question is: How can I add for example the create date to the primary key, or just remove the fact to have a primary key on this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it,

I needed to add:

```
   * @ORM\Id
```

In my created field:

```
  /**
   * @var datetime $created
   *
   * @ORM\Id
   * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
   * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
   */
  private $created;
```

It made what I wanted!

Here are the documentation:
https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-id

Comment: Ok just a comment: Doctrine doesn't know how to use a date as a primary key. So I went back and remove all the "@ORM \Id" and created a normal index.